# Best DB storage with single index

Tags: database, storage, nosql

I need to receive and store dozens of gigabytes of millions of events every month.

Each event has unspecified set of attributes plus always ID and Timestamp field.

I need a rapid scalable storage to store and access this events with following features:

1) quick write operation
2) quick read by range of Timestamp (no need to ready by ID)
3) schema-less (no predefined set of columns)
4) cheap
5) easy to maintain (replication from the box, etc)

Standard relational databases do not satisfy p 3, 4 and 5. 
Cloud NoSQL database, namely DynamoDB, does not satisfy p2 and 5 (and apparently 4).

What would you advise? There should be a simple solution for such common task!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data as XML. SQL Server supports this, then you just have to read and parse from one field, whilst having structured data. For the Timestamp part I'm not sure what you need, but could you have a timestamp associated with each record? Then you can ensure this is indexed which meets your point 2.